# ExtJS make grid to be 100% height

Tags: javascript, extjs4

i found 2 similar questions here, but they are not helped me, my code is:

```
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    autoScroll: true,
    // if set this to any numeric value, then everything works just good, but 
    // i was hoping that `ExtJS` already can detect browser window height, am i wrong ?
    height: '100%', 
    title: 'Products',
    store: store,
    itemId: 'product_grid',
    columns: [.. columns skipped ...],
    plugins: [ rowEditing ],
    dockedItems: [ ..addRow button here..]
});
var panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    autoScroll: true,
    items: [
    {
        xtype: 'productGrid'
    }
    ]
});
Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
    layout: 'fit',
    items: panel
});
```

What i need i scrollable grid filling whole browser window, but grid here does not expand
in height, so if grid has 0 rows, then it has 0 height and when i push "Add row", then
added row looks obscured by scrollbars and this looks ugly.

Also when grid contain more rows than could fit in browser window, then page scrollbar appears (not grid's scrollbar!) and this scrolls whole page so button bar scrolled away,  which is also undesirable and ugly.

Any ideas what is wrong with my setup.

**UPDATE:**

Finally fixed it, intermediate panel should also contain **layout: 'fit'**

Comment: i expirimented with changing layouts, but no success

Comment: when i add dynamically row, then i think i should call something like doLayout, but on which component ?

Comment: `Ext.ComponentQuery.query` returns an array of components. If you're accessing a single component by ID, you might as well use `Ext.getCmp` to get it directly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a couple things you can do here. First, use the `fit` layout on your Viewport as it will force its child component to fill the available space. Second, grids are panels. You don't need to nest a grid in a panel, and probably shouldn't.

The `autoScroll` config doesn't work on grids. Scrolling in both directions is enabled by default, but if you need to change it use the `scroll` property. Lastly, the `height` config only takes a number and doesn't work with strings or percentages. If you specify a height, it overrides any height given by the layout manager and you don't need it for `fit` layouts.

```
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title:       'Products',
    store:       store,
    itemId:      'product_grid',
    columns:     [/* ... */],
    plugins:     [rowEditing],
    dockedItems: [/* ... */]
});

var viewport = Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
    layout: 'fit',
    items:  [grid]
});
```

Comment: It'd be easier to figure out what's going wrong if you posted a screenshot. Also, how are you adding your row?

Comment: Just fixed it, forgot to add `fit` layout option to intermediate panel, my bad. And yes, `layout: fit` is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a viewConfig to the grid, strangely enough, solved my problem of gridpanel having no explicit height in floating window with vbox layout, containing just a form and a grid.

```js
xtype: 'gridpanel',
store: 'DCLocations',
columnLines: true,
autoScroll : true,
viewConfig : {
        emptyText : i18n.message.noresultstodisplay,
},
```